# i am trying to install Redis desktop Manager on Cent OS 6.9

Tags: redis, centos

### I am trying to install redis deskop manager by following these steps

1) cd src/

2) ./configure

3) qmake-qt5 && make && sudo make install

4) cd /usr/share/redis-desktop-manager/bin

5) sudo mv qt.conf qt.backup

---

but at 3rd step i am getting error message, but i found these steps in `http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/#centos`

### Error Message

```
[kumarp@localhost src]$ qmake-qt5 && make && sudo make install
bash: qmake-qt5: command not found
```

Comment: try with `qmake && make && sudo make install`

Comment: i am getting this error  "bash: qmake: command not found

Comment: After a long time. Do you have qt installed?

Comment: no i am new to linux environment, so i don't know exactly, i hope i did not installed qt

Comment: `sudo yum install qt5-qtbase-devel`

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security  <br/>
Setting up Install Process  <br/>
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  <br/>
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org  <br/>
 * extras: centos.blazar.mx  <br/>
 * updates: mirrors.tripadvisor.com  <br/>
No package qt5-qtbase-devel available.  <br/>
Error: Nothing to do  <br/>

Comment: Google: how install qt on centos